# How to make link_to have custom class name in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

How would I generate the following link using [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) helper `link_to`?

```
<a class="bold" href="//address.com">A link</a>
```

When you go like this

```
.bold = link_to 'bla-bla-bla'
```

it produces

```
<div class="bold">
  <a href="blog/3">bla-bla-bla</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need following:

```
= link_to 'A link', '//address.com', class: 'bold'
```

It will generate corresponding HTML:

```
<a class="bold" href="//address.com">A link</a>
```